# Require any instance of a template

Tags: templates, systemd

Is it possible to tell my unit file to wait for any instance (unknown instance name) of a template unit file?

Something like this: After=template@*.service

Example:

I have this template file (template@.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=TemplateFile
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh ${JBOSS_START_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${JBOSS_HOME}/bin/jboss-cli.sh ${JBOSS_STOP_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And i have this unit file (other.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Other
After=network.target
#Requires=template@[a-zA-Z0-9]*.service

[Service]
Type=idle
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gedit
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want the other.service unit only to run when at least 1 instance of template@.service is running

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay :) Edited my question!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the instantiated unit part of a custom target.. then require the target in other.service.

Comment: This just moves the problem into the target's definition. How do I tell the target to depend on *any* instance, like `Requires=template@*.service`?